# No puedo agregarle Sombras a un icono de Font Awesome

Tags: css

estoy teniendo problemas con agregarle sombra a iconos de Font Awesome al hacerle hover, pero si me toma el color. Incluso comenté todos los estilos de la pagina para que haya nada aplicado que me pueda interferir
desde ya muchisimas gracias

```
.social ul li a:hover {
    color: aliceblue;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #2f45e8;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si estas cargando fonawesome como `svg`, no funciona porque es un icono, no texto, para que funcione necesitas el `css` de `fontawesome`.

```css
.fa-globe{text-shadow:3px 6px rgba(255,165,0,.75)}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css">

<i class="fas fa-10x fa-globe"></i>
```

Otra opción es usar la propiedad `filter:drop-shadow`

```css
.fa-globe{filter:drop-shadow(10px 5px 1px blue)}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/js/all.js"></script>

<i class="fas fa-10x fa-globe"></i>
```

Respuesta adaptada de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54450578/5675636).